# Javascriptの関数が2度以上実行できない

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Javascript でfunction関数でチャートを定義し、複数チャートを記載しました。
チャート以外の関数は、複数記載しても動作しますが、添付のチャート関数は、複数記載しても複数の動作が確認できませんでした。
理由に関して、ご指導頂けませんでしょうか。

index.html_case16

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="Shit_jis">
  <title>chart of results</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--ここにグラフが挿入されます-->

</br>

<div style="width: 50%; height: 50%;">
<canvas id="myLineChart" style="width: 50%; height: auto;"></canvas>
</div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

  <script>
    function test_case(){
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myLineChart");
      var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: ['8月1日', '8月2日', '8月3日', '8月4日', '8月5日', '8月6日', '8月7日'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: '最高気温(度）',
              data: [35, 34, 37, 35, 34, 35, 34, 25],
              borderColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
            },
            {
              label: '最低気温(度）',
              data: [25, 27, 27, 25, 26, 27, 25, 21],
              borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1)",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
            }
          ],
        },
        options: {
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: '気温（8月1日~8月7日）'
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                suggestedMax: 40,
                suggestedMin: 0,
                stepSize: 10,
                callback: function(value, index, values){
                  return  value +  '度'
                }
              }
            }]
          },
        }
      });
    }
    test_case();
  </script>
  </br>
  </br>

  <script>
    test_case();
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 「複数記載して複数の動作」で具体的にどうなって欲しいかを明示すると回答できるかもしれません。「チャートの内容を更新したい」だったり「複数チャートを並べたい」だったり。

Comment: 本題とは関係ありませんが、`</br>` でなく `<br/>` と書きたかったのではないでしょうか。また HTML5 では単に `<br>` と書けば OK です。

Comment: 「複数チャートを記載」というのは、具体的は何をすることですか？　質問に書かれているプログラムのtest_case関数は、"myLineChart"というidが付けられたCanvasにチャートを描くものです。そのため、繰り返し呼び出しても、同じCanvasに同じチャートが繰り返し描かれるので、見た目は変わらないと思いますよ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

関数呼び出し `test_case()` は2回実行されています。「関数が2回呼び出されたこと」をどのように確認していますか？　もし「グラフが2つ描画されない」ことから疑っているのであれば、それは間違いです。たとえば `test_case` の関数定義の中に `console.log` を仕込めば、2回出力されていることが分かります。

グラフが2つ描画されないのは、どちらの呼び出しでも id が `myLineChart` の canvas に描画しているからです。